# Exercise 6, Section 6.6 of Hoffman’s Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, proof-writing, diagonalization, projection

> True or false? If a diagonalizable operator has only the characteristic values
> $0$ and $1$, it is a projection.

**My attempt:** Suppose $T:V\to V$ is diagonalizable with eigenvalue $0$ and $1$. Then $\exists B=\{\alpha_1,…,\alpha_n\}$ basis of $V$ such that $\forall i\in J_n$, $\alpha_i$ is eigenvector of $T$. Let $\alpha_1,…,\alpha_r$ and $\alpha_{r+1},…,\alpha_n$ are eigenvectors corresponding to eigenvalue $1$ and $0$, respectively. Let $\alpha \in V$. Then $\alpha =\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\cdot \alpha_i$. So $T(\alpha)= \sum_{i=1}^n a_i\cdot T(\alpha_i)= \sum_{i=1}^r a_i\cdot \alpha_i$ and $T^2(\alpha)=T(T(\alpha))=T(\sum_{i=1}^r a_i\cdot \alpha_i)= \sum_{i=1}^r a_i\cdot \alpha_i$. Thus $T^2(\alpha)=T(\alpha)$, $\forall \alpha \in V$. Hence $T$ is a projection. **Is my proof correct?**

Comment: Slight variation of above proof: Since $T$ is diagonalizable with eigenvalue $0$ and $1$, we have $\exists B$ basis of $V$ such that $A=[T]_B=\begin{bmatrix} I&0\\ 0&0\\ \end{bmatrix}$, where $I$ is $r\times r$ identity matrix. So $A^2= \begin{bmatrix} I&0\\ 0&0\\ \end{bmatrix}=A$. Which implies $T^2=T$. Thus $T$ is a projection.

Comment: Yes, both are correct. (Implicitely assuming $\dim V<\infty$.) You can also formulate it in terms of a direct sum.

Comment: @AnneBauval ohh yes. $V=W_0\oplus W_1$, where $W_0,W_1$ are eigenspace of $0,1$, respectively. We can construct basis of $V$ from basis of $W_0$ and $W_1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Aliter:**

Diagonalizable operators have minimal polynomials with distinct linear factors.

Therefore, in this case $m_T(x)=x(x-1)\implies T^2=T.$